PySpark filter error [NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR] on Azure-Databricks
I'm using Databricks with PySpark and encountering the following error:
Error:
[NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR] Argument `Condition` should be a Column or str, got Column.

Here is my code:
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.filter(col('foo_column').isNotNull())

This code works perfectly when executed in a Databricks notebook. However, when I run the same code from a .py file, I encounter the above error.
At this time, the .py file is called from Notebook.
How can I resolve the error in the first example? Am I missing something?
Additional Information:

Using Databricks Connect
PySpark version: 3.5.0
Python version: 3.10.12

Interestingly, the following code works without any issues:
df = df.filter(df['foo_column'].isNotNull())

Upon further investigation, I noticed that the return type of col differs when executed in a Databricks notebook compared to running from a .py file:
Notebook: pyspark.sql.column.Column
.py file: pyspark.sql.connect.column.Column

I have additional information to share. The issue is not due to the difference between executing in a notebook and a .py file. The error occurs when creating the Spark session using DatabricksSession.builder.getOrCreate().
